# Pre-existing voxel tools/libraries for Java

Tags: java, rendering, voxels

I want to do some development using voxel data as well as rendering it. My interest is more in the project its self, rather then things like working out rendering optimization techniques and working efficiently with large data sets, which I know have been done a billion times by other people.

However, all the existing libraries I can find seem to be for other languages. I have found PolyVox, which seems great, but I'd really much rather use Java for this.

Are there any **fleshed out** libraries? If not,I'm assuming I'm stuck using LWJGL and building something from scratch. Can anyone recommend some thorough tutorials on the subject?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Development with voxel data IS rendering it and optimizing it.  I don't know what it would be without having to do that stuff.